# Retornar número com Expressão Regular

Tags: php, javascript, regex

Tenho uma lista de artigos do Art. 1º até o Art. 2.040., mas em cada artigo existem outros números.

Gostaria de fazer uma expressão que: 
1 - Capturar os números sempre depois da string "Art. " até o espaço depois do número; 
2 - Excluísse os pontos e o símbolo de numeral "º";

Gostaria de fazer uma expressão regular que retornasse apenas os números do artigo.

Este é o código que usei, porém, em alguns artigos ele gera um numero estranho

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $novalinhas);
$artigo = $str;
```

Mas assim, ele pega todos os números da string

---

Resolvi a questão assim:

```
              preg_match('/[0-9]+/', $novalinhas, $matches);
              $artigo = implode(' ',$matches);
              echo $artigo;
```

Mas, não sei se é a melhor forma.

Comment: o q vc já tentou?

Comment: preg_match_all('/(\d+)/', $novalinhas, $matches);
$artigo = implode($matches[0]);

echo "</ul>";        
echo '<ul id="artigo' . $artigo . '" class="artigo">';

Comment: Coloquei um teste aqui
http://preliminarte.com.br/converter.php

Mas, no artigo 6 ele sai errado

Comment: Gostaria de fazer uma expressão que:
1 - Capturar os números sempre depois da string "Art. " até o espaço depois do número;
2 - Excluísse os pontos e o símbolo de numeral "º";

Comment: Você pode editar a sua pergunta adicionando o código e explicando mais detalhes do seu problema, aumentando assim as suas chances de obter uma resposta de qualidade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Já não faço PHP à uns tempos, [cá vai](http://3v4l.org/HRlJt):

```
$artigos = [
    "Art. 1 lala 23",
    "Art. 2 lala 23",
    "Art. 3 lala 23",
    "Art. 4345 lala 23",
    ];
$artigos_len = count($artigos) -1;

for ($i=0; $i <= $artigos_len; $i++) {
    preg_match("/Art\. (\d+)/i",$artigos[$i],$match);
    echo "<ul class='artigo {$match[1]}'></ul>\n\r"

}
```

---

a parte importante aqui é `preg_match("/Art\. (\d+)/i",$artigos[$i],$match);` esta linha apanha, de cada item da lista de artigos, uma expressão regular que *tem* que ter "Art. NUMERO" mas não lhe interessa o que vai além disso.

`(\d+)` refere-se a um grupo de numeros que pode ter um ou mais digitos, servindo para nós depois usar-mos o `$match[1]` onde `1` é o numero deste mesmo grupo.

Comment: cool (+1); talvez `preg_match_all` ?

Comment: @JJoao sendo que ele quer o primeiro numero depois da palavra "Art." não vejo o porque de chamar o `_all` quando a string só tem um possible-match -- pelo que percebi da pergunta, claro :)

Comment: Tens razão é pouco claro (falta um exemplo) (eu imaginei um texto com vários ocorrências de "Art. \d"); mas relendo, provavelmente o OP queria algo como referes.